# What does it mean for argument handling to be "rigid"?

Tags: ruby

Taken from the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F) for `Proc#lambda?`:

> Returns true for a Proc object for which argument handling is rigid. Such procs are typically generated by lambda.

What is "rigid argument" handling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lambdas will raise an ArgumentError if passed the wrong number of arguments, Proc.new won't.

Example:

```
lam = ->(x){ "OK" }
lam.lambda? # => true
lam.call # => ArgumentError
lam.call(1) # => OK

proc = Proc.new { |x| "OK" }
proc.lambda? # => false
proc.call # => OK
proc.call(1) # => OK
proc.call(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) # => OK
```

Comment: There are two differences between `Proc`s that are lambdas and `Proc`s that aren't argument handling and `return`. In both cases, lambdas behave like methods and `Proc`s behave like blocks. It's easy to remember: "lambda" and "method" are both Greek, "block" and "proc" rhyme.